# grant command syntax error near password in shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am stuck with an issue with shell scripting.

I have already used `\` character before double quotes `(")` because of some reason, as in the following line of my shell script.

> sql2=\"grant all on \${db_name}.* to \${db_user}@\${host} identified by \${db_pass};\";

But as in the MySQL "grant" command syntax, I need to put double quotes before and after `\${dbpass}`, which is the part of the shell script line I given above.When I put like this, `\"\${dbpass}\"`, it is throwing syntax error during execution.What should I need to solve this.

This is the shell script which I want to run.

> ssh -t qbadmin@10.3.2.0 '
>   su root -c "
>     echo \"Give db name :\";
>     read db_name;
>     echo \"Give password :\";
>     read db_pass;
>     host=localhost;
>     sql1=\"create database \$db_name;\";
>     sql2=\"grant all on \${db_name}.* to \${db_name}@\${host} identified by \"\${db_pass}\";\";
>     sql3=\"\${sql1}\${sql2}\";
>     echo \"==============\";
>     mysql -u root -p -e \"\${sql3}\";
>   ";
>   '

Please refer this script and please let me know the necessary changes i need to do with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double escape, surrounding the `\${db_pass}` bit with `\\\"` (that's the escaping sequence for `\"`).

Like this:

```
ssh -t qbadmin@10.3.2.0 '
su root -c "
echo \"Give db name :\";
read db_name;
echo \"Give password :\";
read db_pass;
host=localhost;
sql1=\"create database \$db_name;\";
sql2=\"grant all on \${db_name}.* to \${db_name}@\${host} identified by \"\\\"\${db_pass}\\\"\";\";
sql3=\"\${sql1}\${sql2}\";
echo \"==============\";
mysql -u root -p -e \"\${sql3}\";
";
'
```